# $M$ is a manifold and isometrically embedded in $X$, homotopy type of $M$ is determined by polyhedrons $P$ s.t. $M\subseteq P \subseteq X$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

This is the setting.

$M$ is a compact, connected Riemannian manifold without boundary. and it is isometrically embedded in some larger metric space $X$ ($X$ is not necessarily manifold). So, one can just say $M\subseteq X$.

Then, if every polyhedron $P$ such that $M\subseteq P \subseteq X$ can be retracted to $M$ in $X$, can we say $X$ itself is homotopy equivalent to $M$?

This question is motivated by the Proposition 3.2 of the paper "On neighborhoods of the Kuratowski imbedding beyond the first extremum of the diameter functinoal" by Mikhail Katz.
Here is the link. https://eudml.org/doc/211844

I tried some searching. It seems that theory of ANR (absolute neighborhood retract) is related, but I'm not sure. Is this already well-known fact? If so, what is good reference for this?

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand the question, but isn't this a counterexample: $M$ = circle, $X$ = $M$ + attached Warsaw circle?

Comment: That is exactly the reason I said `No'! KGEO probably needs to reformulate to avoid pathological local behaviour in $X$.

Comment: Oops..you are right. we need more conditions for $X$. Maybe local contractibility? or linearity as Tim Porter already pointed out?

Comment: And I think $X$ should be CW-complex, also.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some questions that might help you answer yours.

(i) What conditions are you putting on $X$, e.g compactness? Some form of local niceness, ....? In Katz's paper it looks to be a linear space, which is much more specific than the general formulation you pose.

(ii) What conditions on the retractions, are they, as in 3.2 of Katz's paper, deformation retractions?

(iii) Have you considered the Borsuk shape (or possibly the strong shape) of $X$? (I suspect `not yet' as you just mentioon ANRs.)

If $X$ does not have the shape of a CW-complex, then my guess is that the answer  to your question is No. However my feeling is that you might reformulate the question with a bit more precision first (i.e. to avoid some pathological, and perhaps, silly, counterexamples.)

There are results on flows and their relationship with shape theory and proper homotopy theory that may be useful for the general area, although I have not checked (work by Sanjurjo, also Hernandez and coauthors).